# Sencha Command generate form generates view instead

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

Using Sencha Cmd v6.1.2.15 The following command creates a new view in views folder instead of a new form in forms folder. What's wrong? Am I missing something here?

```
sencha generate form -n product -f name:string,createdOn:date,modifiedOn:date,currentAmount:number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me, just saw in the docs that sencha generate view is ExtJs specific, while sencha generate form is Touch specific.